# Sonarqube jenkins integration

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I am triyng to intergate jenkins and maven with sonarqube.
I am completed with prerequistes and installation part
there is ome error related to class not loading, i am confused what is the reason behind this.

**JENKINS PIPELINE**

```
 stage('Test & code quality check ') {
      withMaven(maven: 'M3'){
    withSonarQubeEnv(credentialsId:'mbk-sonar',installationName:'sonar-qube') {
        sh '''mvn sonar:sonar -X  -f  /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag/cabs-stagSrc/pom.xml \
  -Dsonar.projectKey=mobikwik-jenkins \
  -Dsonar.projectName=mobikwik-jenkins \
  -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonar.mobikwik.com\ /
  -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 \
  -Dsonar.language=java \
  -Dsonar.sources=/var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag/cabs-stagSrc/shared-objects/src/main/ \
  -Dsonar.java.binaries=/opt/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/classes'''

    }
      }
  }
```

JENKINS CONSOLE OUTPUT- [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project root: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.report.MetadataPublisher: Unable to load component class

```
Injecting SonarQube environment variables using the configuration: sonar-qube
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ mvn sonar:sonar -X -f /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag/cabs-stagSrc/pom.xml -Dsonar.projectKey=mobikwik-jenkins -Dsonar.projectName=mobikwik-jenkins -Dsonar.host.url=http://10.20.15.26:9000 -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.language=java -Dsonar.sources=/var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag/cabs-stagSrc/shared-objects/src/main/ -Dsonar.java.binaries=/opt/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/classes
----- withMaven Wrapper script -----
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dmaven.ext.class.path="/var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag@tmp/withMaven42e8b7cd/pipeline-maven-spy.jar" -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.maven.reportsFolder="/var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag@tmp/withMaven42e8b7cd" 
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/M3
Java version: 1.8.0_222, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/local/openjdk-8/jre
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.9.0-11-amd64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[DEBUG]   Included /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag@tmp/withMaven42e8b7cd/pipeline-maven-spy.jar
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.ext
[DEBUG]   Included /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag@tmp/withMaven42e8b7cd/pipeline-maven-spy.jar
[INFO] [jenkins-event-spy] Generate /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag@tmp/withMaven42e8b7cd/maven-spy-20200912-110023-7696240343729296116878.log.tmp ...
[INFO] 11:00:26.484 Project key: mobikwik-jenkins
[INFO] 11:00:26.485 Base dir: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag/cabs-stagSrc
[INFO] 11:00:26.485 Working dir: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag/cabs-stagSrc/target/sonar
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.486 Project global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.488 Creating module hierarchy
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.488   Init module 'mobikwik-jenkins'
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.489     Base dir: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag/cabs-stagSrc
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.489     Working dir: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag/cabs-stagSrc/target/sonar
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.490     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.490   Init module 'mobikwik-jenkins'
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.490     Base dir: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag/cabs-stagSrc/cabs-api
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.491     Working dir: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag/cabs-stagSrc/cabs-api/target/sonar
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.491     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.492   Init module 'mobikwik-jenkins'
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.492     Base dir: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag/cabs-stagSrc/core
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.492     Working dir: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag/cabs-stagSrc/core/target/sonar
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.493     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.493   Init module 'mobikwik-jenkins'
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.494     Base dir: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag/cabs-stagSrc/shared-objects
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.494     Working dir: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag/cabs-stagSrc/shared-objects/target/sonar
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.495     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.495   Init module 'mobikwik-jenkins'
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.495     Base dir: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag/cabs-stagSrc/mbk-service
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.496     Working dir: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag/cabs-stagSrc/mbk-service/target/sonar
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.496     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en
[INFO] 11:00:26.501 Load project settings for component key: 'mobikwik-jenkins'
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.522 GET 200 api/settings/values.protobuf?component=mobikwik-jenkins | time=20ms
[INFO] 11:00:26.523 Load project settings for component key: 'mobikwik-jenkins' (done) | time=22ms
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.530 No language available
[INFO] 11:00:26.537 Load quality profiles
[DEBUG] 11:00:26.550 GET 200 http://10.20.15.26:9000/api/qualityprofiles/search.protobuf?project=mobikwik-jenkins | time=12ms
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for root 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] root ............................................... FAILURE [  2.222 s]
[INFO] shared-objects ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] core ............................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] mbk-service ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] cabs-api ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.638 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-12T11:00:26Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [jenkins-event-spy] Generated /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag@tmp/withMaven42e8b7cd/maven-spy-20200912-110023-7696240343729296116878.log
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project root: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.report.MetadataPublisher: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.rule.QualityProfiles: No quality profiles have been found, you probably don't have any language plugin installed. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project root: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.report.MetadataPublisher
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: No quality profiles have been found, you probably don't have any language plugin installed.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[Pipeline] }
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeed?
[Pipeline] // withSonarQubeEnv
[Pipeline] }
[withMaven] Jenkins Task Scanner Plugin not found, don't display results of source code scanning for 'TODO' and 'FIXME' in pipeline screen.
[withMaven] Publishers: Pipeline Graph Publisher: 2 ms, Dependencies Fingerprint Publisher: 68 ms, Open Task Scanner Publisher: 1 ms
```

Comment: Did you install any language lessons in SonarQube (not Jenkins)? As of 7.X, SQ will analyze all code for which an analyzer is installed; language=java is ignored. "No quality profiles have been found, you probably don't have any language plugin installed."

Comment: Hi, when i tried to create quality profle in quality profile tab i am not able to do so, there is an alert there showing "here are no languages available. You cannot create a new profile.".Now question how to add a language.

Comment: What happened that the response is no longer answered .. ?"u led me to correct path". Seemed like it was answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have not [installed any language plugins](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/install-plugin/) in SonarQube (not Jenkins).

> `org.sonar.scanner.rule.QualityProfiles: No quality profiles have been found, you probably don't have any language plugin installed. -> [Help 1]`

As a SonarQube Admin, log into SonarQube. From the main menu, **[Administration |  Marketplace](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/marketplace/) ...**, filter on "**Languages**" for Sonar provided languages, "**External Analyzers**" for third party. "Install" as necessary, Restart required.

As of 7.X, SQ will analyze all code for which a language analyzer is installed; `language=java` is ignored.

Comment: Thanks Ian, u led me to correct path, do u have any good tutorial for passing jacaco coverage report to sonarqube as well, without doing any changes to pom.

Comment: Jacoco+SQ is messy. Look for a separate existing Q. Or ask a new onei if not found.